# Limit addition of oval objects to line object in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to associate one object to another in Tkinter. I would like to add ovals onto my Tkinter canvas but only to a pre-existing line object, i.e., I do not want the user to be able to add ovals anywhere on a canvas except for on the line object. Is there another way to do this other than restricting the addition of the oval to the x0, x1, and y0, y1 min/max of the pre-existing line object? Thanks in advance!

Comment: unless you are expecting a Yes or No answer, do you have any code you can share with us of your attempts to do so? and any associated error messages?

Comment: The only code I have is for restricting the addition of the oval to the x0, x1, and y0, and y1 min/max of the pre-existing line object. This is what I would consider to be an indirect approach and I am looking for something that might link the two objects together.

Comment: Would it help to include this code?